# Get Failed Messages with KafkaListener

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka latest version and using @KafkaListener. I am using BatchListener. In the method that is listening to the list of messages i want to call the acknowledge only if the batch of records are processed. But the spring framework is not sending those messages again until I restart the application. So I used stop() and start() methods on KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry if the records were not processed but I feel like its not a good way of solving the problem. Is there a better way of handling this.

Comment: In my view point that is the one of the best way to do it, and second way is to separate these failed messages into another topic and reprocess them all

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation for the `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#seek-to-current).

> The `SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler` seeks each partition to the first record in each partition in the batch so the whole batch is replayed. This error handler does not support recovery because the framework cannot know which message in the batch is failing.

Comment: I looked at it but it seems like that will only be invoked if there is an error in the BatchListener, and in my case there is an error handling the processing of the events in that case I need to seek the events myself and that is what I did and it worked. Can you please confirm my assumption

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work; why not just throw an exception and let the framework do the seeks for you? But yes, of course, you can do the seeks yourself if you so wish.

Comment: I did throw an exception but it did not do the seek, I was throwing the Exception from the method that was annotated with @KafkaListener. Also the acknowledge method does not tell me if the offset was committed so I am going to call the commitSync on the kafka consumer so that i can track if the commits happened. On a separate note this kafka spring framework is awesome and I love it and it does so much of the boilerplate code for me. Thanks for the awesome framework